# how to access a method inside onMounted in vue3 composition api?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

what I am trying to do is to access a method after the setup is done and page is mounted in composition API but vue is not accessing the method

what I am doing wrong?
here is my code -

```
export default defineComponent({  
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      this.calcStartIndex();
    });
    return {};
  },
  methods: { 
    calcStartIndex() {
      console.log("startIndex");
    }
  },
})
```

The error I am getting -

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'calcStartIndex')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare method inside `setup` function

```
export default defineComponent({  
  setup() {
    function calcStartIndex() {
      console.log("startIndex");
    }

    onMounted(() => {
      calcStartIndex();
    });

    return {};
  },
})
```

or even better with usage of `script setup`

```
<script setup>
  function calcStartIndex() {
    console.log("startIndex");
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    calcStartIndex();
  });
})
</script>
```